# Можно ли написать собственный код, и не вставлять его каждый раз в код?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

class Sound {
private boolean released = false;
private Clip clip = null;
private FloatControl volumeC = null;
private boolean playing = false;

public Sound(File f) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.addLineListener(new Listener());
        volumeC = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        released = true;
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        released = false;
    }
}

//true если звук успешно загружен, false если произошла ошибка
public boolean isReleased() {
    return released;
}

//проигрывается ли звук в данный момент
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return playing;
}

//Запуск
/*
  breakOld определяет поведение, если звук уже играется
  Если reakOld==true, о звук будет прерван и запущен заново
  Иначе ничего не произойдёт
*/
public void play(boolean breakOld) {
    if (released) {
        if (breakOld) {
            clip.stop();
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
            playing = true;
        } else if (!isPlaying()) {
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
            playing = true;
        }
    }
}

//То же самое, что и play(true)
public void play() {
    play(true);
}

//Останавливает воспроизведение
public void stop() {
    if (playing) {
        clip.stop();
    }
}

//Установка громкости
/*
  x долже быть в пределах от 0 до 1 (от самого тихого к самому громкому)
*/
public void setVolume(float x) {
    if (x<0) x = 0;
    if (x>1) x = 1;
    float min = volumeC.getMinimum();
    float max = volumeC.getMaximum();
    volumeC.setValue((max-min)*x+min);
}

//Возвращает текущую громкость (число от 0 до 1)
public float getVolume() {
    float v = volumeC.getValue();
    float min = volumeC.getMinimum();
    float max = volumeC.getMaximum();
    return (v-min)/(max-min);
}

//Дожидается окончания проигрывания звука
public void join() {
    if (!released) return;
    synchronized(clip) {
        try {
            while (playing) clip.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {}
    }
}

//Статический метод, для удобства
public static Sound playSound(String s) {
    File f = new File(s);
    Sound snd = new Sound(f);
    snd.play();
    return snd;
}

private class Listener implements LineListener {
    public void update(LineEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            playing = false;
            synchronized(clip) {
                clip.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Можно куда нибудь вставить этот код, чтобы не писать его каждый раз в программах? Что бы было что-то типа `import ...`, так как. мне нужно отсюда одно действие `Sound.playSound("D:\\User\\Загрузки/lll.wav").join();`.

Работаю в NetBeans.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вставлять этот код в каждом новом проекте, созданном в NetBeans?

Comment: Упакуйте класс в jar и подключайте в остальных проектах, можно в локальный maven-репозиторий загрузить

Comment: @MrFylypenko Я имею ввиду, что-бы **не** вставлять каждый раз этот код в проект, и что-бы в проектах можно было использовать **Sound.playSound("D:\\User\\Загрузки/lll.wav").join();**

Comment: Используйте сборщик проектов (maven) или добавляйте jar файл в проект, как подсказывает carapuz. Это самый простой и быстрый способ

Comment: @MrFylypenko Спасибо.

Comment: @carapuz Я упаковал, а дальше что делать?

Comment: А дальше добавляете jar в свой classpath

Comment: @carapuz А в коде что писать?

Comment: А в коде импорт Вашего класса и работа с ним

Comment: @carapuz так как импортировать?

Comment: import .........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо упаковать класс в jar-архив.

Comment: Только не проект, а jar-архив

Comment: @carapuz Спасибо, исправил.